# Getting the current time as a float

Tags: android, time

We have an app that saves the pulse and time in a file. Now we want to show it in a graph. For the graph, we use [this library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).
To add entries, we use this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayListTime.size(); i++) {
        entries.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(arrayListTime.get(i)), Float.parseFloat(arrayListPuls.get(i))));
    }
```

The enty can only be made with float values, but arrayListTime saves long values converted to string. The problem is, that parsing it to float cuts off the last numbers and the time is not accurate anymore.
We get the time from

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
arrayListTime.add(Long.toString(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
```

So is there a way to get the time as a float?

Comment: (Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes()/60.0f);

Comment: Why do you need to parse it to String? Simply change Long.toString() to (float) (calendar.getTimeInMillis());

Comment: I need to parse it to String because I want to write it into a file and read it afterwards. When I use (Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes()/60f), can I format it with simpleDateFormat?